# Can’t import class from JAR despite JAR including it (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, jar

At my workplace I was required to download a project in Eclipse using git. It turns out Eclipse is showing errors on import (“The import  cannot be resolved.”). The project requires JARs included in Maven Dependencies.

I searched the contents of JARs and they seem to include what is being searched (picture #2 com.sun.jna.Native). What’s even more interesting a class is being imported from the troublesome JAR so the project is aware of the existence of those JARs (com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser).

I tried typing import on my own and see how far typing help can go. I got to “com.sun.jna” but couldn’t find “.Native” part.
I assume it's problem with my project build options or Eclipse settings as my coworker is able to run the code without problems. I'm using Eclipse Neon.

Thank you for taking your time to read my problem.

Images attached:

1. Overview of problem.
2. Searched classes are included in JARs.
3. Using tips to see how far I can go in search of searched elements. (Too low reputation to post)

Ps. I'm a noob

[image: demo]

[image: demo]

Edit 1:
I gave a try updating POM dependencies. Two jars I would like to be able to import in my project are jna-4.1.0.jar and jna-platform-4.1.0.jar as they seem to be the ones causing problems.

For dependencies details I went here :
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.1.0
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform/4.1.0

I added two entries to dependencies section to pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
<artifactId>jna</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
<artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Upon ctrl+s I got Error:
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.

Errors are still being detected where they were being detected previously.

Edit 2:

Not sure if error is fully solved but it appears so. I can't recreate fully the steps I took ot solve the problem. At one point I started clicking a lot of things randomly. I believe it was Right click on project -> Maven → Install. Upon doing so a lot of things was printed to the console and among them there was Loc header error. Following some instruction I deleted already downloaded jar on my computer and used maven to redownload them (using going to folder containing pom file from maven console).
Redownload fixed the issue.

Sorry I can't provide step-by-step solution but there was a lot of random clicking involved and it was quite a long time ago. Thank you everyone for help.

Comment: Is the jar in your build path in Eclipse? Check the differences between your project files and your colleagues project files.

Comment: What JDK is your project configured to use? Is it the same version as your coworker?

Comment: Results of "java -version"
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

<Post in progress>

Comment: We haven’t compared our JDKs version but it’s safe to assume it’s newest or almost new. We have compared our projects files and there were alike. 

Jar is included to project. Proof http://i65.tinypic.com/6s6ex2.jpg

Comment: What does your `pom` look like?

Comment: Is that part of the maven dependencies container in Eclipse (then try to run Alt+F5 refresh on the project enabling cleanand build) or user defined JARs? In that case check the build path for access rules and exclusions. And make sure your Java version 8 is used by eclipse.

Comment: Alt+F5 didn’t work. I don’t understand what you are asking about (too noob). Let me know what you need and I will provide it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your packages set up, your class can not find the jar in the package. If this is a maven project (as you said it is), you can create (or edit your existing) pom file to include the dependencies for each jar you have used. Then you don't even need them attached it will do it for you. If you have already done that and it still does not work, check your version numbers. You may have the wrong version number and be trying to use a jar that no longer has what you are importing. You use the [Maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/), search up your jar name and find the correct version number. You add them after the `</build>` but before the `</project>` tab in your pom.xml file and follow this structure for each jar:

```
</build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.blahblah</groupId>
      <artifactId>desktopBlah</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  ...more dependencies listed her....
    </dependencies>
  </project>
```

Comment: Well done! I had a reference to the installed jar as local maven repository, e.g. `file://${project.basedir}/build-repo`, but that wasn't enough. Adding the dependency resolved the missing package.

Answer (score 0):

For jna native classes, you need to have the corresponding DLLs in the path  (%PATH% variable)  besides having the Jar in the CLASSPATH.